# Unable to upload a big file to server behind nginx as a reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, files

I use nginx as a reverse proxy. Behind it is coming apache hosing foo.com . In order to upload a big file, I set `post_max_size = 20M` and `upload_max_filesize = 20M` in php.ini . But I can't upload file with size bigger than 2MB. My nginx configuration is:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name  .foo.com;
if ($http_host != "www.foo.com") {
    rewrite ^ http://www.foo.com$request_uri permanent;
}
access_log /var/log/nginx/foo.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/foo.error.log;

index index.php index.html;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:80/;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    proxy_buffering off;
    chunked_transfer_encoding on;
   }
}
```

In addition I configured nginx.conf as following:

```
http {
...
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 600;
    client_max_body_size 200M;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
    proxy_connect_timeout       600;
    proxy_send_timeout          600;
    proxy_read_timeout          600;
    send_timeout                600;
...
}
```

Any ideas on how to solve the problem?

Comment: What are you using to POST? Curl might be adding an Expect header

Comment: I tested and used many browsers, like IE or Firefox. Neither of them got the true result.

Comment: @MohsenSaberi did you try increasing nginx and PHP logging to pinpoint the reason? Also, do you receive any kind of HTTP code when the connection is cut? You could use a proxy or sniffer to know exactly what the HTTP response looks when it cuts transmission

Answer (score 1):

In nginx.conf set the max body size.

*client_max_body_size 20M;*

Also GoTo /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.

***post_max_size = 100M***

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.

***upload_max_filesize = 100M***

Comment: These configurations are also set, but don't answer.

Comment: Set 
client_max_body_size 200M;
in
/etc/nginx/proxy_params;

Comment: Added the parameter to proxy_params. The file content is:
`proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
client_max_body_size 200M;`
But yet I can't upload file with size bigger than 2MB.

Answer (score -1):

Add this parameters to `http` section of your nginx.conf:

```
proxy_connect_timeout       300;
proxy_send_timeout      300;
proxy_read_timeout      300;
proxy_buffer_size       512k;
proxy_buffers           32 4m;
proxy_busy_buffers_size     25m;
proxy_temp_file_write_size  10m;
```